# REGEX in MYSQL not working?

Tags: mysql, regex

I have the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM 'users'
WHERE (
 summary REGEXP '^\\(?[\\d]{3}\\)?[\\s-]?[\\d]{3}[\\s-]?[\\d]{4}$' OR
 bio REGEXP '^\\(?[\\d]{3}\\)?[\\s-]?[\\d]{3}[\\s-]?[\\d]{4}$' OR 
 about_me REGEXP '^\\(?[\\d]{3}\\)?[\\s-]?[\\d]{3}[\\s-]?[\\d]{4}$'
);604-456-1234
```

I already tested the regex here --> http://rubular.com/ and it works for my cases.

I have one user with the following string on its bio "604-456-1234" and it should be returned but is not.

Why?

Comment: I didn't have closer look at your query so I can't give you specifics for your query, but the regex in ruby is certainly not identical to the one in MySQL, so it is not particularly surprising if it does not match when devloping using rubular.com

Comment: If you have a large table and need to perform that query regularly, you are going to have significant performance problems, as you will need to do a full table scan to complete the query. If this is a regular part of your system where you need to find users with phone numbers in their information, perhaps you would consider adding a `has_phone` tinyint filed to query against and just set this field upon data insert based on the presence of phone info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My mistake you are doing it wrong [\d] doesn't work, you need to use [0-9], so using:

```
'^\\(?[0-9]{3}\\)?[\\s-]?[0-9]{3}[\\s-]?[0-9]{4}$'
```

Works, specifically look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html there is no reference to `\d` being supported

Comment: Hey one more question, do you know how to make the regex match "asdasdadsad (604)456-1234" ... right now it only matches "(604)456-1234" if there's nothing else in the string. Thx @nrathaus

Comment: Remove the ``^`` from the start, ``^`` means "begins with"